# how to download and link a different version of node with brew?

Tags: angularjs, angular, npm, nvm

I have node: `7.1.0` that I installed with brew and I want to go back to `4.4.6`.

The issue is that now I somehow unlinked the node cause I thought i dont have npm but when I did `brew install npm` I got:

> Warning: node-7.1.0 already installed, it's just not linked

so now how can I get ver `4.4.6` and link it instead of the `7.1.0`?

Answer (score 1):

Use nvm

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

```
nvm install 4.4
nvm install 7.1
```

when you need 7.1 or 4.4 use

```
nvm use 7.1
# or
nmv use 4.4
```